# Performance Overhead on SQL Server Temp Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I use temp tables frequently to simplify data loads (easier debugging, cleaner select statements, etc).  If performance demands it, I'll create a physical table etc.

I noticed recently that I automatically declare my temp tables as global (##temp_load) as opposed to local (#temp_table).  I don't know why but that's been my habit for years.  I never *need* the tables to be global but I'm curious if there is additional overhead for creating them as global.  And should I work on changing my habits.

Are there additional risks for making them global?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-Global temp tables are pretty much guaranteed never to collide.

Global temp tables are similar to materialized tables in that the name needs to be unique per server.

**As a rule, only use `##GLOBAL_TEMP` tables when you must.**

Otherwise, if you are writing a proc that could me run more than once simultaneously, the procs will interact with each other in unpredictable ways, making it extremely difficult to troubleshoot - `Instance 1` can change data being used by `Instance 2` which causes `Instance 3` to generate incorrect results as well.

My personal opinion on Temp tables is that I only use them when:

- I have a medium-to-large resultset (more than 1m rows)
- I will need to index that resultset
- I will not need to use that resultset more than once per iteration of the process
- **I am confident I will not need to resume the process at any point**

I highlighted that last bullet because this is the main reason I try to minimize temp table use:

If you have a long-running process, and you use temp tables to store intermediate data sets, and something dies say 90% of the way through, you have to **completely restart** if that data is not in a materialized table most of the time.

Some of my processes run for days on billions of rows of data, so I am not interested in restarting from scratch ever.

Comment: Some awesome points there.  The collision issue occurred to me even as I was writing my question. Thanks!

Comment: I've actually yet to find a good use case for global ##temp tables. This is a rhetorical question, but why not just create a permanent table and then drop it? You get the same concurrency limitations without losing the table if anything dies. You could argue whether that's better or worse, I suppose, just like you could argue that a gunshot wound is better or worse than a crossbow wound.

Comment: I assumed that physical tables had additional overhead (logging, caching) vs temp tables.  Is this false?  I usually use temp tables for small(ish) datasets.  I primarily data warehouse (900k fact records per day) and my source shadows and staging are all physical. I typically use temp tables for some simple lookups and supporting joins.

Comment: @Tricky - Yes that's correct on logging but you can also create a "normal" table in `tempdb` to take advantage of the logging optimisations as long as you don't need the data after service restart.